# How to fix error "npm ERR! could not detect node name from path or package" when building simple app with docker and nodeJS?

Tags: docker, docker-build

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hi there');
});
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Listening on post 8080");
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

docker build .

```
npm ERR! could not detect node name from path or package

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T23_36_35_301Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I cannot understand why this does not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set a [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) then copy your files to that directory:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app

RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

As explained in the docs:

> The `WORKDIR` instruction sets the working directory for any `RUN`, `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, `COPY` and `ADD` instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the `WORKDIR` doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

On `npm`'s Github repo, a similar error was mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1975#issuecomment-724807696) as part of the issue on [npm not working when run outside a package directory](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1975). It seems related only to new versions of `node` and `npm` (node v15.x, npm v7.0.x as of the bug report):

> Fresh install of Node 15.1.0 and `npm i -g npm@7.0.9`, that for some (probably unrelated) reason don't work properly.
> ...
>
> ```
> 24 verbose stack TypeError: could not detect node name from path or package
> ...
> 28 verbose node v15.1.0
> 29 verbose npm  v7.0.8
> 30 error could not detect node name from path or package
> ```

But in your case, you *do* have a package.json, so it's probably because the `build` command can't find it without setting a proper `WORKDIR`. So, rather than to work it around with `npm`, just make sure to always set a `WORKDIR`. It's recommended anyway as mentioned in the [`WORKDIR` section of Docker's best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir):

> For clarity and reliability, you should always use absolute paths for your `WORKDIR`. Also, you should use `WORKDIR` instead of proliferating instructions like `RUN cd … && do-something`, which are hard to read, troubleshoot, and maintain.